# How can I find the n indices of minimum elements for each row using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For example:

```
n = 2
p1 = np.asarray([[20, 30, 10],
                 [10, 20, 30],
                 [30, 20, 10]])
```

As a result, I want:

```
[ [0, 0, 2],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [2, 1, 2] ]
```

The first number in each row is just the line number in p1. The remaining n numbers are the indices of minimum elements of the row. So:

```
[0, 0, 2]
 # 0 is the index of the first row in p1.
 # (0, 2 are the indices of minimum elements of the row)


[1, 0, 1]
# 1 is the index of the second row in p1.
# (0, 1 are the indices of minimum elements of the row)

[2, 1, 2]
# 2 is the index of the third row in p1.
# (1, 2 are the indices of minimum elements of the row)
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What `minimum elements` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to find the top two minima:

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
p1 = np.asarray([[20, 30, 10],
                 [10, 20, 30],
                 [30, 20, 10]])

pos = np.argpartition(p1, axis=1, kth=2)

res = np.hstack([np.arange(3)[:, None], np.sort(pos[:, :2])])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0 0 2]
 [1 0 1]
 [2 1 2]]
```

Once you find the minima use [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to concatenate the index of the rows and to it.